# Using DBMS_SQL.Execute_and_fetch - Get cursor number of a Ref Cursor (10g)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Using Oracle 10g DBMS, I want to apply `DBMS_SQL.execute_and_fetch` in a procedure. I refuse `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as I want to bind named variables and don't depend on their order in the statement.

The problem is that I cannot get a handle on the cursor number of the `olist` ref cursor parameter passed into my procedure. Here is a sample code snippet of what I'm trying to do.

```
PROCEDURE TestProc( vuserid INTEGER,
                    olist   OUT refcur)
IS
  cursor_num INTEGER;
  vsql       VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
BEGIN
  vsql := 'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = :user_id';

  /*creates a new cursor. Need to use the cursor that is passed to my procedure*/
  /*cursor_num := dbms_sql.open_cursor; */

  /*Only available in 11g onwards        */
  /*cursor_num := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(olist); */

  sys.dbms_sql.parse(cursor_num, vsql, sys.dbms_sql.native);
  sys.dbms_sql.bind_variable(cursor_num, ':user_id', vuserid);
  sys.dbms_sql.execute_and_fetch(cursor_num, FALSE);
END TestProc;
```

How to successfully use the `DBMS_SQL.execute_and_fetch` procedure in my particular case whereby the cursor used for the fetch is the ref cursor I pass in?

Comment: I assume `olist` must be an `IN` parameter, isn't it?

Comment: Hi Wernfried. No, it is OUT as written. I am calling the procedure using ODP.Net and as per documentation it should be OUT. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featRefCursor.htm#i1008035)

Answer (score 0):

I asssume you are looking for this:

```
PROCEDURE TestProc (
      vUserid   INTEGER,
      olist              OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
   cursor_num INTEGER;
   vSQL VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
    result NUMBER;
BEGIN   
    vSQL := 'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = :user_id';

    cursor_num := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_num,vSQL,DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_num, ':user_id', vUserid);
    result := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_num);
    olist := DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(cursor_num);

END TestProc;
```

Then the calling block can use `FETCH olist INTO...` or `FETCH olist BULK COLLECT INTO...` to get the result of your query.

But you must run at least Oracle 11, before it was not available.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried. But I have not choice. I am using 10g as I said in my question to begin with. Otherwise I could have used DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(oList) to get the cursor number. What I wanted was a way to get the cursor number in 10g. Thanks.

Comment: Well the cursor number is simply value of `cursor_num`. `TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(olist)` you can use after `OPEN olist FOR SELECT ...`, e.i. `cursor_num` is equal to `TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(olist)`

Comment: Yes, but I am sorry - you are missing my point. I need to do one of these things in 10g - not 11g. Whether I use TO_CURSOR_NUMBER or (as in your code DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR) is useless to me as they are both unavailable to 10g. Is there a way to do any of this in 10g? Thanks again. T

Comment: Then it is not possbile unless you upgrade to Oracle 11g. BTW, Oracle 10 is alomost as old as Windows XP and out of support since long time.

Comment: I am well aware of this but that is not something that is under my control. I work with what I have at my disposal. As it happens we will be upgrading to 12c in the next 6 months but I have a release build due in one month so that is not an option.